# Vue2 v-text works incorrectly

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

I'm just start using Vue2 and in one page I just need simple form submission and validation. The issue is when error is thrown I want to show it below each of the form inputs but error is shown only after I start to fill in some of that inputs, not immediately after error.

HTML:

```
<div class="container" id="app">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <h1 class="text-center login-title">Sign in to continue</h1>
        <div class="account-wall">
            <form method="POST" action="/account/login" @submit.prevent="onSubmit" @keydown="clearErrors($event.target.name)">

                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" autofocus v-model="email">
                <p class="alert alert-danger" v-if="errors.email" v-text="errors.email"></p>

                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" v-model="password">
                <div class="alert alert-danger" v-if="errors.password" v-text="errors.password"> </div>

                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and js code:

```
    app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        errors: {}
    },
    methods: {
        onSubmit() {
            axios.post('/account/login', {email: this.email, password: this.password})
                .then(response => alert('Wahoo!'))
                .catch(errors =>
                    Object.keys(errors.response.data).forEach(
                        key => this.errors[key] = errors.response.data[key][0]
                    )
                )
        },
        clearErrors(errorName) {
            delete this.errors[errorName];
        }
    }
});
```

So when error is catched Vue root elemens is updated but errors is not shown
[image]

and only after I start fill in some of the field the other erros are 
appearing
[image]

I know it can be done much better, but I need it as quick/simple as possible. Thanks for any help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have not defined `errors.email` and `errors.password` in the data part, they are not [reactive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats), so when  only `errors.email` changes, these does not update the DOM.

You can use [vm.$set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set) to *Set a property on an object. If the object is reactive, ensure the property is created as a reactive property and trigger view updates*

See the working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cjnyarp9/1/).

Vue code:

```
methods: {
  onSubmit() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.$set(this.errors, 'email', 'email errror')
        this.$set(this.errors, 'password', 'password errror')
      }, 300)
    },
```